# How to get password reset frequency from Gsuite Admin SDK Apis

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

I need the to get password policy and password reset frequency of the Gsuite account through the gsuite Admin SDK Apis. But, I dont find any api doc regarding this.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/

I need to fetch the password expiration time and policy using Oauth 2.0 google admin Sdk apis.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports)  to query various [Login Audit Activity Events](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/login)  including [Account password change](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/login#password_edit)

For this:

- Use the method [activities.list()](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list)
- Set `userKey` to either `all` or a specific `user email`
- Set `applicationName` to `login`
- Set `eventName` to `password_edit`
- If desired, you can narrow down the results by specifying additoinal parameters, like e.g. `startTime`, `endTime` or `filters`